# BeansValidation in CDI and servlet application

Tags: java, servlets, el, cdi, bean-validation

I have next problem with my project for studies. I need to have working BeansValidation in my simple servlet project with CDI. I want beans validation to work with cdi beans annotated with scope annotation, but for now, when I try to validate such beans(even if they have some errors), validator claims that there is no errors at all.

Additionaly it will be nice to set beans properties with EL language to values from request, which seems to work with beans with scope annotation, but it doesn't work with any others beans.

I think that it is some problem with CDI proxies, but I have no idea how to solve it. I use maven to build my application and deploy it on Jboss 7.1.1.Final.

Here are all sources in my project:

Bean with scope annotation:

```
package pl.lab3.bean;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Scoped {
    @Size(max = 2)
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Bean without scope annotation:

```
package pl.lab3.bean;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Named
public class Data {
    @Size(max = 2)
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Servlet:

```
package pl.lab3.servlet;

import pl.lab3.bean.Data;
import pl.lab3.bean.Scoped;

import javax.el.ELContext;
import javax.el.ExpressionFactory;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

public class ServletDispatcher extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    private Validator validator;
    @Inject
    private ELContext elContext;
    @Inject
    private ExpressionFactory expressionFactory;
    @Inject
    private Scoped scoped;
    @Inject
    private Data data;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        this.request(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        this.request(request, response);
    }

    private void request(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        try {
            expressionFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "${scoped.name}", String.class)
                    .setValue(elContext, "test");
            String goodValue = scoped.getName(); //returns test, as expected
            //but in debugger it's still null(first screen)
            Set<ConstraintViolation<Scoped>> emptySet = validator.validate(scoped); //doesn't work, returns empty set

            scoped.setName("test2");
            String goodValue2 = scoped.getName(); //obviously works, but still null in debugger(same first screen, just nothing happened)
            Set<ConstraintViolation<Scoped>> emptySet2 =
                    validator.validate(scoped); //doesn't work too, returns empty set

            expressionFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "${data.name}", String.class)
                    .setValue(elContext, "test");
            String badValue = data.getName(); //above doesn't work, and in debugger too(second screen)
            Set<ConstraintViolation<Data>> emptySet3 = validator.validate(data); //empty set...

            data.setName("test2");
            String goodValue3 = data.getName(); //obviously works, and I can see good value in debugger(third screen)
            Set<ConstraintViolation<Data>> errors = validator.validate(data); //and here I've got expected error

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Screnshots from debbuger mentioned in servlet code:

Screen1:

[image: screen1 with scoped bean and null value]

Screen2:

[image]

Screen3:

[image]

And some(I think) less important files:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>pl.lab3.servlet.ServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://jboss.org/schema/cdi/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>lab</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <artifactId>lab3-validation</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>lab3-validation</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.seam.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>seam-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-web-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>validation</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because your CDI objects are managed by the CDI container.  When the validator tries to find the class, it's getting some proxy class name, not the object you're dealing with.  You should not make your model/transport objects CDI managed.

Comment: I thought that problem lies near the cdi proxies. But the question is how to solve this? I have idea to get real object from proxy and then pass it to validator. It will be nice to do this in proxy to validator(as I wrote in commet to @Gunnar answer). I think it will be nice if validator works(or imitate to work) on cdi beans.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add you constraints on the property level (i.e. on getter methods instead of fields).

Comment: Your workaround works fine. But it will be nice to property level annotations works too. I tried the idea to pass real object to validate method instead of cdi proxy. I recieve real object by calling BeanManager.getContext().get() with appropriate parameters, and then it works. For nice and invisible solution I think that custom validator producer will be nice, in this producer I will return proxy to validator object, and in this proxy when the first argument of method is cdi proxy I will change it to real object. But the question is how to check if some object is a cdi proxy or a real object?